# How to get images by username and tag - Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram

There is a similar question here: [Instagram: Get photos by user and tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344346/instagram-get-photos-by-user-and-tag) which doesn't really solve this problem. Is it really the case that the Instagram API is just not capable of this without sifting through all Instagram images of a certain tag and finding those matching a specified username?

I am using this PHP API: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Using the API searching by user looks like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&count=10
```

And searching by tag:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cat/media/recent?client_id=CLIENTID&count=10
```

I've tried this: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cat/media/recent?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN` with no joy.

Anyone else had better luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way, you have to first get all photos from a user using API and then search for the hashtag using string match in photo caption or tags.

There is an implementation of this in gramfeed, for example open http://gramfeed.com/krisrak, and then use the keyword search to match hashtags